# How do you upload a csv file to google sheets using the google sheets api with c#?

Tags: c#, csv, restsharp, google-sheets-api

I have a method that pulls a csv from a website using restsharp.

```
 class ScheduledBilling
{

    public string Report()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
        client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("username", "xxx", "password", "xxx");
        var request = new RestRequest("/login", Method.POST);


        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);


        var ScheduledBilling = client.DownloadData(new RestRequest("/file));
        var csv = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(ScheduledBilling);

        return(csv);

    }

}
```

In main, I've been using a mix of tutorials and the quickstart so that I can enter information into a google sheet.

```
//ScheduledCRMBilling.Report();
            ScheduledCRMBilling obj = new ScheduledCRMBilling();
            string csv = obj.Report();

        String spreadsheetId2 = "xxx";
        String range1 = "Scheduled Billing";

        ValueRange valueRange1 = new ValueRange();   

        valueRange1.MajorDimension = "ROWS";//"ROWS";//COLUMNS

        var oblist1 = new List<object>() { csv };

        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest update1 = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange1, spreadsheetId2, range1);

        update1.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW;

        UpdateValuesResponse result1 = update1.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine("done!");
```

I've set the range to be the entire sheet (Scheduled Billing). What happens is that the first cell is filled with all the information in the csv, and not as if you would import a csv into google sheets. How should I proceed? 
I feel as if I should pass the csv variable as a list of strings, which would place a string in each cell. But then I don't know how it would know when it's time for a new line.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367466/5209435.The question is about python but inside the google reference docs that are linked you can select .NET.

Comment: I was actually just looking at that. I thought batchUpdate was used if you have more than one range? And in this case isnt selecting the entire sheet one range? Also i'm not sure how to combine these two sources, the documentation isnt very beginner friendly... Like im not sure how to pass pastedatarequest

Comment: Are you able to use the Google Drive API instead of the Sheets API?

Comment: I'd actually be even more lost if I went that route. How would I use a pastedatarequest with a batchupdate? The documentation seems very lacking.

Comment: Since you don't have enough rep to chat, join me here https://discord.gg/cR3q5f. Then I'll try to help you out. Full disclosure I've never used the Google Sheets or Drive APIs before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer I linked on the OPs question the Sheets API does not provide functionality to upload a sheet, only to create one from scratch.

Had to end up using the Drive API as this allows for uploading of files. Especially relevant is this section about [uploading google docs types](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk18wzxhzdk19) as they will get converted to the appropriate type. So your CSV file will be turned into a Google Sheet.

If your spreadsheet is in memory aka stored in a variable, you can replace this line:

```
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("files/report.csv",
                    System.IO.FileMode.Open))
```

with the following:

```
using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csv)))
```

Before call the upload functionality you will have to create the credentials for your application using [this guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet), you will also have to change the scope to `Drive`. Below is a small application that I put together to demonstrate the whole upload flow - assuming you have created the OAuth token for the Drive API and downloaded the secret into your project.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
        private static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };

        private static string ApplicationName = "CsvTest";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive.googleapis.com1.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
            {
                Name = "My Report",
                MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
            };

            var csv = "Heading1,Heading2,Heading3\r\nEntry1,Entry2,Entry3";

            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csv)))
            {
                request = service.Files.Create(
                    fileMetadata, stream, "text/csv");
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }
            var file = request.ResponseBody;

            Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can change `Name` and `Application` to whatever you like they're just friendly names.

**EDIT**

Happy coding.