# Upload CSV to Google Sheets using gspread

Tags: python, csv, drive, gspread

I have a Json object which needed to be uploaded to the Google Spreadsheet. I have searched and read various resources but could not find the solution. Is there a way to upload object or csv from locally to google spreadsheet using gspread. I will prefer not to use google client api. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can import CSV data using [`gspread.Client.import_csv`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.Client.import_csv) method. Here's a quick example from the docs:

```
import gspread

# Check how to get `credentials`:
# https://github.com/burnash/gspread

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# Read CSV file contents
content = open('file_to_import.csv', 'r').read()

gc.import_csv('<SPREADSHEET_ID>', content)
```

This will upload your CSV file into the first sheet of a spreadsheet with [`<SPREADSHEET_ID>`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id).

**NOTE**

This method removes all other worksheets and then entirely replaces the contents of the first worksheet.